# Indexed Pages missing from Google SERP

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, google-index

Some of the indexed pages on our completely disappeared from search results and then appeared after a few days, and now it disappeared for over 2 weeks, no matter how directly I searched for them, and making changes didn't help. The pages don't show up even when looking up by the title verbatim, does not appear on the results.

I know that just because a page is indexed, it does not always mean it will be served up on Google. However, those indexed pages ranked very well and have come in the top 10 search results for the past few years. Out of the blue, it's disappeared from search results now.

I checked GSC, everything seems to be normal. No issues at all!

**Any idea why this happens? Please don't give some generic SEO advice.**

I'm banging my head against the wall to resolve this indexing bug. These indexing bugs/issues are always the trickiest to figure out.

So if anyone knows what could be causing this or how we could fix this, any feedback is appreciated.
**How do I reach out to the Google Team?**

Comment: Your question "How do I reach out to the Google Team?" clearly not relevant to the purposes of this forum.

Comment: Only you can determine what is wrong with your indexing.  You haven't even specified the pages in question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.